# Seven friends want to play a game. They must be divided into two teams with three people in each team and one leader. In how many ways can they do it?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Seven friends want to play a game. They must be divided into two teams with three people in each team and one leader. In how many ways can they do it?

Can someone please help me with this. I have gone through many of the possibilities but have not found the right answer.

Thanks.

Comment: What were the possibilities you went through?

Comment: Are the teams distinguishable or fungible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First choose 3 peoples from 7 $${7\choose 3}=35$$ you will have choosen one team till here

For second team, choose 3 peoples from left 4 $${4\choose 3}=4$$

And multiply $$35\times 4=140$$

But the order doesn't matter as pointed out by Ross Millikan , so answer should be $$\frac{140}{2}=70$$

Comment: This is only true is the two teams are different.

Comment: @Arthur , thanks for pointing out , but it has become interesting for me now , what should be the answer if both teams are same ?? And what does it mean for having two same teams ?? All members are identical ??

Comment: @AtulMishra:  The question is whether you care which team is the first one picked.  As I read the question, if the people are $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ it is the same if you pick $a,b,c$ for the first team and $d$ as the leader, leaving $e,f,g$ for the second team or if you pick $e,f,g$ for the first team and $d$ as the leader.  If the first team picked will be the home team, it does matter what the order is and your answer is correct.  If it does not, you should divide by $2$ because you have counted each configuration twice.

Comment: @AtulMishra Sorry for the comment I was answering the wrong post

Comment: Yes @RossMillikan , but can you please explain it to me that what should the same teams mean as pointed out by Arthur, does this mean all the members of both team are identical??

Comment: @AtulMishra:  Yes, in my example you can see the two teams are $a,b,c$ and $e,f,g$ but you have two ways to pick them.  In the first you pick $a,b,c$ and $e,f,g$ are left over at the end.  In the second you pick $e,f,g$ and have $a,b,c$ left over at the end.  If all you care about is the grouping, these are the same.  Each grouping will be counted twice in your original $140$.  If you distinguish between the first and second team, say by home field or color of uniforms then the order matters and your original count of $140$ is correct.

Comment: Ohh thats the way it is @RossMillikan thanks for your precious time

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the players are different, there are $\binom{7}{3}=\frac{7!}{3!4!}$ ways of choosing $3$ players from $7$. Then there are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways of choosing $3$ players from the remaining $4$. We then divide by two so that the order doesn't matter.

Thus there are $\frac12\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{3}=\frac12\times 35\times 4=70$ ways of choosing the two teams.

Comment: You should divide by $2$ because the order you pick the teams is does not matter.

Comment: @RossMillikan, Thanks you were right about dividing by 2.